# How to stop music apps from playing when connected via Bluetooth to my car/headset/receiver?

Tags: music-player, bluetooth-audio

We recently bought a used Toyota Prius that has Bluetooth installed with the JBL audio system. Whenever my phone (stock Nexus 4 running 4.4.4) connects to it, the car sends a "play" command that automatically starts the most recently used music app (Google Play Music, Pandora, etc.). It doesn't matter if no music app was open on the phone, the command opens it up and it starts playing no matter what, and there's no way on the car to stop it from sending the command, as [mentioned here](http://priuschat.com/threads/how-do-i-stop-jbl-system-from-auto-playing-bluetooth.122355/). Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Interestingly, I have the opposite experience.  When a bluetooth device is connected, the Android device *always* loads the factory Music app, and not the most recently used music app.  I would prefer it to load the most recently used music app.

Comment: Unable to post as an answer, but a simple solution uses the (free) Automate app from LlamaLab together with a very simple script (Prevent Bluetooth Autoplay).

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle Hi, it's been a while. This question has been unprotected, so perhaps you want to convert your comment as a proper answer? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a [Bluetooth connect & Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player&hl=en) app that can intercept the incoming "play" command. While it was originally designed to let you start a specific music app playing when a specific Bluetooth device connects, you can instead select "STOP music from playing" to keep any app from starting when the car connects.

Comment: Sounded promising but didn't work for me. Combination of OnePlus One (Marshmallow) and audio system of Renault.

Comment: This has worked for me for both Android 8.0 and 9.0. Just need to remember you have it installed if you need to change the settings...  :)

Comment: Does not work for me either.  I can't believe such a simple thing isn't a default setting in the bloody phone...

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings, Applications, Application Manager, and then Modify System Settings. Find the player that is starting (for me it's Samsung Music) and switch the toggle to OFF.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it's not correct on Android 8.1.0. Wherever they moved this setting to (could they please stop moving things all the time and invalidating answers on the internet?), I cannot find it (I have used it in the past...).

Comment: In current Android versions, you can search in settings to find this (i.e. "Modify system settings").

Comment: It dosn't work like this any more. I find non of my music player apps (that open a player notification on bt connection) in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another work around if other method fail, if the android phone always use the same music player to autoplay when bluetooth is connected. Just create a silent mp3 file and rename it AAA.mp3, this will ensure it will be the top of the file list. make it like 5 minutes or 1 hour, whatever you want. file size will be bigger though.

In my case, it will always use the default music player to autoplay. So i just put only that silent mp3 in the playlist. It will still autoplay, but a silent audio. Then I just turn on my favourite music player or podcast.