# How do I stop music apps from opening in the background/a notification when turning on bluetooth/bluetooth tries to auto-connect

Tags: notifications, bluetooth, music, music-player, bluetooth-audio

As an avid music listener I have several music apps on my phone. Everytime I turn on bluetooth (or when bluetooth tries to autoconnect to a device without any device to connect to) several of my music apps open a player notification.

This is really annoying, especially as it slows down my phone while the apps are opening in the background (unless it has something to do with bluetooth connecting). This also replaces the current player notification (if I have one) on my homescreen, which is annoying.

Is there a way to disable this?

My phone is an Sony XZ2 Compact running Android 10.
The music apps I experience this with are: Spotify, Bandcamp, Mixcloud and DR Lyd.

Update: The answer to [How to stop music apps from playing when connected via Bluetooth to my car/headset/receiver?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77558/how-can-i-stop-music-apps-from-playing-when-my-android-connects-via-bluetooth-to) doesn't solve it.

I've tested the app [Bluetooth Connect & play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player) which doesn't solve it.

I've tested [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179460/158409) with Tasker and it didn't solve it.

Comment: Hi. For all of these apps you can disable the app component responsible for receiving and acting on bluetooth events (probably targeting the intent bluetooth state changed). I don't know if this can be done without root access or not. Another solution is to use an automation app which should listen to "Connected to bluetooth device", and then dismiss all notifications that appear within X milliseconds/seconds from blacklisted (denylisted) apps.

Comment: @Firelord would I be able to do this with an app like Tasker (which I already use) or is there another app with the functionality you could recommend?

Comment: You should be able to use Tasker for this. If that does not work out you can give MacroDroid app a try -- I prefer this app for dismissing any kind of notification.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your suggestions and see if I find a solution.

Comment: FYI: I've found the app [Bluetooth connect & play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player) that I'll test and post an answer with, if it solves my issue.

Comment: Bluetooth connect & play didn't solve it. I'm not great with Tasker, so haven't found a solution yet. The answer in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77558/how-can-i-stop-music-apps-from-playing-when-my-android-connects-via-bluetooth-to doesn't work either. I guess something has changed with Android since the answer was given.

Comment: I've just tested the Tasker implementation in this answer https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179460/158409 which seemed related, but it didn't solve it either. When turning on BT, music apps still open a player notification in the background.